# JQuery AJAX Save sortable portlet items to database

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, portlet, jquery-ui-sortable

I've tried solving my issue with the different posts but nothing seems to work.

I have the following code: http://plnkr.co/edit/pcfz33lzHz4wdehjGEuQ

I want to use AJAX to save the order of the two portlets.  I can figure out how to send the info to the database but I can't figure out how to use AJAX to POST the variables to editsort.php

It should update every time one of the items is moved.

Just to clarify the code there is a div around the portlets that lets you move the portlets all at once.  Pay no attention to that code, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine:

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "updatecoords.php",
          data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need}
        })
```

it is going to pass the `$_POST['x']`, `$_POST['y']` and `$_POST['need_id']` to the specified URL.

Comment: That is for the #set div.  Not for the sortable portlets.